# Conform id to protocol, is it needed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have just been looking at some old code and it got me thinking about which of these to use, both seem to work without complaint. I was just curious when I spotted the difference.

THIS:

```
id <UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

OR

```
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess it depends on what you are asking to appDelegate

i mean, if you are going use the property "window" which is defined in UIApplicationDelegate protocol:

```
NSLog(@"%@",  appDelegate.window);
```

then you should use :

```
id <UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

but if you try:

```
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@",  appDelegate.window);
```

you'll get an error...

Comment: Thank you, yes I was after the "window" property, so that makes perfect sense. Just curious though, if you use bracket notation (which is what I was doing) and write: id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; NSLog(@"%@",  [appDelegate window]); Xcode does not complain, and you don't get an error?

Comment: in this case Xcode doesn't give error, but just because it points to the property "window" declared in UIView (i know, it shouldn't...): try to mouse click on window in [appDelegate window] with the command(apple) key pressed, and you'll go to the class UIView.h declaration of property "window"...

Answer (score 2):

While meronix's answer is correct, it misses an important point.

*You should always declare variables to have the most specific type possible.*

By doing so, you give the compiler the maximum amount of information with which to validate your code.  Thus, this is preferable because it tells the compiler to limit the search for selectors to a minimal number:

```
id <UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = ...;
```

Note that `id<SomeProtocol>` limits the set of valid selectors to *only* those that exist in `SomeProtocol`.   This why you'll sometimes see the protocol declared as also implementing `<NSObject>` or you'll see `id<SomeProtocol, NSObject>` (or `NSObject<SomeProtocol>*`) as the type declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

to avoid any kind of warning